# Significance of the slope of a terminal velocity vs. mass graph

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, kinematics

I am trying to figure out the physical meaning of the slope of a terminal velocity vs. mass graph. My teacher asked this question in relation to lab exploring the relationship between the mass of an object and its terminal velocity.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's a square root function. There isn't a deeper physical meaning apart from the fact that the conventional approximation is that the drag force grows with the square of the velocity. To get twice the terminal velocity, you need four times the mass.

Comment: *"[...] that the conventional approximation is that the drag force grows with the square of the velocity"*. Not necessarily, at low speed $F_D\propto v$, see also Stokes' law: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes'_law#Terminal_velocity_of_sphere_falling_in_a_fluid

Answer (score 1):

The frictional force $f$ on an object mass $m$ travelling through a fluid at a speed $v$ can be approximated to 
$f = k_1 v+k_2v^2$ where $k_1$ and $k_2$ depend on the shape/size of the object, the fluid through which the object is travelling, the temperature of the fluid etc.

The speed when the two terms are equal in magnitude $\dfrac{k_1}{k_2}$ enables one to say that if the speed of the object is much lower than $\dfrac{k_1}{k_2}$ the frictional force is approximately $ k_1 v$  and if the speed of the object is much higher than $\dfrac{k_1}{k_2}$ the frictional force is approximately $ k_2 v^2$.

At the terminal speed $mg- k_1 v_{\rm t}-k_2v^2_{\rm t} =0$ which shows that a more massive object will have a larger terminal speed.

So in the low speed regime at the terminal speed
$mg – k_1v_{\rm t} = 0 \Rightarrow v_{\rm t} \propto m$
and in the high speed regime
$mg – k_2v^2_{\rm t} = 0 \Rightarrow v^2_{\rm t} \propto m$
where $_{\rm t}$ is the terminal speed and the effect of any upthrust has been ignored.

For these two regimes you have either $v_{\rm t} \propto m$ or $v^2_{\rm t} \propto m$ and differentiating these relationships you can see that the gradient of terminal speed against mass graph will be of constant gradient at low speed and proportional to $v^{-1}_{\rm t}$ at higher speeds.
A better way to check the higher speed relationship would be to plot a graph of $v^2_{\rm t}$ against $m$ and see if it is a straight line.

If you used **spheres** of different radius $r$ then the analysis becomes a little more complex because the frictional force is now $f = c_1 rv+c_2r^2v^2$ and the mass of a sphere is $\frac 43 \pi r^3 \rho$ where $\rho$ is the density of the sphere and $c_1$ abd $c_2$ are dependent on the fluid and its temperature.

However you should still be able to find a relationship between the terminal speed and the mass of the object for low and high speeds.

I leave the reader to decide what the relationship is between terminal speed and mass for bodies of different shapes and sizes.